# I have two tables linked by foreign keys, I need to insert data into both tables at once in VB.net SQL Server

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net

Following are the two tables

**Supplier**

```
Supplier ID (PK) - Auto Increment 
Supplier Name
```

**LoginDetails**

```
Username 
Password 
Supplier ID (FK)
```

Comment: What code do you have to start with?  We will help you with your problems, but not write code from scratch for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRAN 
insert into Supplier([Supplier Name]) values
('abce')


if @@IDENTITY is not NULL
BEGIN
insert into LoginDetails(Username,Password) values
('User1','dfd845jdfgdf',@@IDENTITY)
END

COMMIT TRAN
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
ROLLBACK TRAN
END CATCH
```

Answer (score 0):

I did the following way and it worked thanks alot for your effort

```
        sqlString1 = "INSERT INTO Supplier(SupplierName, CompanyRegNo, SupplierCat, SupplierAdd, SupplierContact, SupplierEmail, SupplierStat, RegisterDate) VALUES ('" & txtname.Text & "' , '" & txtcompreg.Text & "', '" & drpcat.Text & "', '" & txtadd.Text & "', '" & txtcontact.Text & "', '" & txtemail.Text & "', 'Active' , '" & DateAndTime.Today & "' )"
        sqlString1 &= "INSERT INTO LoginDetails(Username, SupplierID, Password, Position) values ('" & txtusername.Text & "' ,(Select MAX(SupplierID) From Supplier), '" & txtcpass.Text & "', 'Supplier')"
```